# SQLiteOpenHandler why do we need the Context variable?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've started programing my first app in android, and noticed that in the constructor of SQLiteOpenHandler that is:

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
```

I have a "Context" variable which role is unclear to me, because my intuition is to think that only one DB could exist with the same name NO mattar in what context I create it.
 I've looked in the [manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) and it said:

> Parameters: 
>   context     to use to open or create the database

which did help me figure out the Context role ether.
Therefore, I'd like to ask

1. What is the role of the Context in the DB creation?
2. Will different Data Base instances will be created for different Contexts but same DB name, factory and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the role of the Context in the DB creation?

It is needed to obtain your app's package name when constructing the full package-private path for the database file.

Specifically, [`Context.getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) called by `openOrCreateDatabase()`, called by `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

> Will different Data Base instances will be created for different Contexts but same DB name, factory and version?

No, provided that the contexts are withing the same app i.e. share the same package name defined in the manifest.

If the apps are different, the app-private data paths will be different and the database files will be different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! Could you tell where you found this information (I haven't found it in the Manual :( and it's really important)

Comment: @user3717551 laalto is a __God father of__  `SQLite`. He has very outstanding knowledge about `SQLite`.

Comment: Yeah i have no dough in it :) 
But i have done a lot of googling before I've asked and find nothing... So i guess that i am doing some thing wrong or just did know where to look before i ask [it must be trivial judging by the negative value of my question]

Comment: @user3717551 The information is right there in the code. For example, http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java